# Why is getWritableDatabase() necessary to create a SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I want to create a SQLite database.
So I followed a tutorial and I have these two lines in my MainActivity that create the database.

```
LugaresDB lugaresDB = new LugaresDB(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = lugaresDB.getWritableDatabase();
```

My question: I expected just the first line to create the database, but it doesn't create it.
I have to add the second line. Why?

Comment: The first line creates an object, not a file. Similarly, `new File(...)` creates an object, not a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how the framework is implemented.

It's not possible to say exactly why it is implemented as such, but generally it is a good design idea to follow principles of [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): a constructor is only responsible for object instance initialization. Any other actions such as actually opening the database with file I/O are undesirable side effects. These other actions are better modelled as methods with verb in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is the way the class is implemented. Your `LugaresDB` seems to be a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. The first line creates a helper object of class `SQLiteOpenHelper` which can be used to create either a read-only or writable instance of `SQLiteDatabase`, which is what the second line does.